# Pastespecial Range from one workbook to another using SpreadsheetGear

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

`daughter.Worksheets["DataLoad"].Range[1, 1, t.APIs.Count, 1].EntireRow.Copy(Master.Worksheets[DataLoad.Name].Range[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex + t.APIs.Count, 1].EntireRow);`

copies all formulas and formats and pastes into the range in the .Copy overload 
I cant seem to figure out how to paste just values or just values and formats.
My attempt:

```
daughter.Worksheets["DataLoad"].Range[1, 1, t.APIs.Count, 1].EntireRow.Copy(Master.Worksheets[DataLoad.Name].Range[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex + t.APIs.Count, 1].EntireRow, PasteType.ValuesAndNumberFormats)
```

gives the error no overload for method copy takes 2 arguments. Ive been looking online for awhile now and I cant seem to figure out what should be a trivial solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for IRange.[Copy](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Copy.html)(...).  You should find an [overloaded option which accepts 5 arguments](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Copy(IRange,PasteType,PasteOperation,Boolean,Boolean).html), the second of which is a [PasteType](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.PasteType.html) enumeration that allows you to choose what aspects of the range should be copied.  Example:

```
srcRange.Copy(destRange, PasteType.Values, PasteOperation.None, false, false);
```